# Reading placeholder only works with White space

Tags: java, spring-boot

For some reason my bean is only reading placeholder from application.properties like this:

```
@Value("$ {clientCreation.applicationAcronym}")
```

If i use it like this, spring says it cant find this placeholder :

```
@Value("${clientCreation.applicationAcronym}")
```

Any idea why?

```
IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'clientCreation.applicationAcronym' in value "${clientCreation.applicationAcronym}"
```

Comment: If what you are claiming is true, it's a Spring Boot defect. Can you show the `applicaiton.properties` and mention Spring Boot version?

Comment: Please also share post your application.properties file here to understand the issue better.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help! I've found the problem. Basically, the app was reading the application.yml from a dependency app.